# python: defaultdict not working with string formatting

Tags: python, dictionary, string-formatting, default-value

This is easy-peasy:

```
'foo {bar}'.format(**{'bar': 0})
```

This doesn't work, yielding a `KeyError`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)
'foo {bar}'.format(**d)
```

Is there a way to accommodate a `defaultdict` in string formatting?

Comment: Keyword arguments are passed as a dictionary, not a `defaultdict`.  I highly doubt that there is an easy way.

Comment: This seems to work in modern Python. What version are you using?

Answer (score 6):

`**` unpacking produces a `dict`, which is why this isn't working. If you're running Python 3.2 or higher though, you can pass the `defaultdict` without unpacking to [`str.format_map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format_map) which exists for precisely the purpose of passing non-`dict` mapping types:

```
'foo {bar}'.format_map(d)
```

**Edit**: Apparently, in Python 3.5 at least, `'foo {bar}'.format(**d)` actually does work with a `defaultdict(int)`, and `d` is modified (after the formatting, the `repr` is `defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'bar': 0})`), so it looks like in modern Python, `format_map` may not be necessary for subclasses of `dict`. Interesting.

Comment: Damn, guess I'm stuck as I'm using 2.7.10.

Answer (score 1):

Given another answer and in a comment, apparently that *does* work in Python3, but in Python2 you need to do something a little more hackish:

```
from string import Formatter
from collections import defaultdict

mystring = 'foo {bar}'
d = defaultdict(int)
parts = Formatter().parse(mystring)
newstring = mystring.format(**{part[1]: d[part[1]] for part in parts})
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [@zondo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36273585/355230) (and to a small degree, [@ShadowRanger's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36273526/355230)), you could do something like this which worked correctly in both Python 2.7.11 and 3.5.1 for me.

```
from string import Formatter
from collections import defaultdict

def string_format_map(fmt, d):
    try:
        str.format_map
    except AttributeError:
        parts = Formatter().parse(fmt)
        return fmt.format(**{part[1]: d[part[1]] for part in parts})
    else:
        return fmt.format(**d)

d = defaultdict(int)
print(string_format_map('foo {bar}', d))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pre-parse the format string: you can use the `vformat` method of the `Formatter` directly:

```
>>> from string import Formatter
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> Formatter().vformat('{foo:<2s}{bar:<5s}', (), defaultdict(str))
'       '
```

That output string has 7 spaces, as the format string specifies.